# how to get a selected item on a spinner using SimpleCursorAdapter from DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I am not able to call a value or item from a DB to a spinner widgets.

I am trying this

```
SimpleCursorAdapter pharmacyDetailsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_doc_pres_closed, PharmacydetailsCursor, from, to);
pharmacyDetailsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.appoint_pres_spinner); 
pharmacyDetailsSpinner.setAdapter(pharmacyDetailsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code..

```
Spinner spn = (Spinner) findViewById(resource_ID);   
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.SPNID, LIST);
spn.setAdapter(adapterVehicle);    
spn.setSelection(POSITION);
```

You can set your spinner position.